# TypeError: invalid key error while trying to get min of two columns row wise in pandas in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Getting `TypeError:"(['guardrails'], ['order_case'])' is an invalid key"` error while trying to get min of two columns row wise in pandas but the above 2 columns exists in the dataframe.

Code line:

`Master_File['Guardrails View'] = min(Master_File[['guardrails'],['order_case']])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax to select multiple columns from a Pandas DataFrame is `df[[column1,column2]]`. Also, since you are trying to take the row-wise minimum of the two columns, you will want to use the [`.min` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.min.html) with argument `axis=1` (the `axis=1` argument is what performs the operation row-wise; the default behavior is column-wise). So in your case, the code would be:

```
Master_File['Guardrails View'] = Master_File[['guardrails','order_case']].min(axis=1)
```

which will append the `'Guardrails View'` column containing the row-wise minimum of `guardrails` and `order_case` to the `Master_File` DataFrame.